# SQL selecting adjacent rows for a adjacent set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble doing the following in SQL with Postgres. My program has an ordered set of numbers. In my database I have the table which stores all numbers in rows with extra data. These rows are also placed in order.

For example my set I need to find is;

```
1,5,6,1,3
```

The database has rows

```
row1 4
row2 5
row3 1
row4 5
row5 6
row6 1
row7 3
row8 2
row9 7
```

In the example above it's easy to see that my set is found from row 3 to to row7. Still doing such in SQL is a mystery to me. I'm reading some articles regarding pivot tables, still I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both data-sets need to have fields that identify the order.

And provided that the ordering column is a sequential consecutive set of numbers, then this is possible, although I doubt it's very quick.

```
Table 1                 Table 2

id | value              id | value
 1    4                  1    1
 2    5                  2    5
 3    1                  3    6
 4    5                  4    1
 5    6                  5    3
 6    1                  
 7    3                  
 8    2                  
 9    7
```

Then this query...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_1
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      MIN(table_1.id)    AS first_id,
      MAX(table_1.id)    AS last_id
    FROM
      table_1
    INNER JOIN
      table_2
        ON table_1.value = table_2.value
    GROUP BY
      table_1.id - table_2.id
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2)
  )
  AS matched_sets
    ON  matched_sets.first <= table_1.id
    AND matched_sets.last  >= table_1.id
```

Comment: If more than one set is found, won't this return the max ID of the last set?... Doesn't matter really though MIN is all the OP asked for.

Comment: @xQbert - It will give a different record for each matched set as `GROUP BY table_1.id - table_2.id` will give a different value for each.

Comment: Thanks, other solutions are maybe faster or less complex. Still this works best for larger queries. Performance is still an issue. But I hope I can optimize it

Comment: Create two indexes on the main table.  (id, value) and (value, id) as one will optimise the inner query, and one will optimise the outer query.  SQL Server's optimiser can then use the statistics to determine which is most helpful.  Beyond that, I'm not sure this approach can actually be improved.  You *may* benefit from making a generalised version of @ErwinBrandstetter's answer using recursive CTEs.

Comment: @CasperBroeren - Recursive version added as separate answer.

Comment: @CasperBroeren: I added a recursive version to my ansewr that should be *much* faster, simpler and actually works in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

#### Recursive version

@Dems beat me to it: a **[recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) is the way to go** here. It works for **any** sequence of numbers. I post my version because:

- It does not require an additional table. Just insert your sequential numbers as array.
- The recursive CTE itself is simpler.
- The final query is smarter.
- It actually works in PostgreSQL. @Dems recursive version is not syntactically correct in it's current state.

Test setup:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (id int, val int);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
 (1,4),(2,5),(3,1)
,(4,5),(5,6),(6,1)
,(7,3),(8,2),(9,7);
```

Call:

```
WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
    SELECT '{1,5,6,1,3}'::int[] AS a
    ), y AS (
    SELECT t.id   AS start_id
          ,1::int AS step
    FROM   x
    JOIN   t ON t.val = x.a[1]

    UNION  ALL
    SELECT y.start_id
          ,y.step + 1                      -- AS step   -- next step
    FROM   y
    JOIN   t ON t.id = y.start_id + step   -- next id
    JOIN   x ON t.val = x.a[1 + step]      -- next value
    )
SELECT y.start_id
FROM   x
JOIN   y ON y.step = array_length(x.a, 1)  -- only where last steps was matched
```

Result:

```
3
```

---

#### Static version

Works for a predefined number of array items, but is faster for small arrays. 5 items in this case. Same test setup as above.

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT '{1,5,6,1,3}'::int[] AS a
    )
SELECT t1.id
FROM   x, t t1
JOIN   t t2 ON t2.id = t1.id + 1
JOIN   t t3 ON t3.id = t1.id + 2
JOIN   t t4 ON t4.id = t1.id + 3
JOIN   t t5 ON t5.id = t1.id + 4
WHERE  t1.val = x.a[1]
AND    t2.val = x.a[2]
AND    t3.val = x.a[3]
AND    t4.val = x.a[4]
AND    t5.val = x.a[5];
```

Comment: @Martin: Thank you, Martin. Seems I have misread the question. The update should provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

how about...

```
Select instr(',' & Group_Concat(mNumber SEPARATOR ',') &',',@yourstring)
FROM Table
```

Whoops that's my SQL have to look up similar functions for Postgresql...

[Postgresql Version of Group_concat](http://mssql-to-postgresql.blogspot.com/2007/12/cool-groupconcat.html)

All this does is group multiple rows into one long string and then do a "Find" to return the first position of your string in the generated long string.  The returned number will match the row_number.  If 0 is returned your string isn't in the generated one.  (may have to be cautious with the ', ' comma space.

Comment: Need to prefix and postfix both strings with `,`.  As otherwise you get a match here by mistake...  `9,10,11,12` against `0,1` (as well as many others)   [`,9,10,11,12,` against `,0,1,` won't match by mistake.]

Comment: Just a quick note to say that as of the current edit, `@YourString` needs to begin and end with `,` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive answer...

```
WITH
  CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    id        AS first_id,
    id        AS current_id,
    1         AS sequence_id
  FROM
    main_table
  WHERE
    value = (SELECT value FROM search_table WHERE id = 1)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    CTE.first_id,
    main_table.id,
    CTE.sequence_id + 1
  FROM
    CTE
  INNER JOIN
    main_table
      ON main_table.id = CTE.current_id + 1
  INNER JOIN
    search_table
      ON  search_table.value = main_table.value
      AND search_table.id    = CTE.sequence_id + 1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  main_table
INNER JOIN
  CTE
    ON  main_table.id >= CTE.first_id
    AND main_table.id <= CTE.current_id
WHERE
  CTE.sequence_id = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM search_table)
```